# Comment exprimer « processed foods » ?

Tags: alimentation

Comment exprime-t-on « processed foods » en français?

Par exemple :

> I don't eat potato chips, because I avoid *processed foods*.

Comment: French Language n'est pas un service de traduction qui remplacerait la consultation d'un dictionnaire en ligne.  Par contre bien sûr nous pouvons donner notre avis sur un mot/une phrase en français. [*Processed food* sur *linguee*](http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/processed+food). *Processed food* sur *Reverso*](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/processedfood).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le terme "produit alimentaire transformé" est celui qui conviendrait le mieux.

Ta phrase donnerait donc en français : "Je ne mange pas de chips, car j'évite les produits alimentaires transformés".

Dans le langage courant (voire familier), en revanche, on ne retrouve pas souvent ce terme... Les français préféreront utiliser "produits industriels" ou "chimiques", même si ce n'est pas une traduction exacte. Par exemple "Je déteste les pains au chocolat industriels, je préfère ceux de la boulangerie", ou alors "Ces chips ont l'air chimiques..." !

Comment: Je suis d'accord pour le langage courant. En revanche, je pense que dans le domaine scientifique, dans l'agro-alimentaire, on parlera réellement de produit alimentaire transformé.

Comment: Il m'arrive d'utiliser l'expression *produits transformés* de temps à autre... Pas souvent certes, mais quand même (notamment quand il s'agit d'expliquer que consommés en trop grande quantité, ils sont néfastes pour la santé)